# What is a progressive clock?

Tags: tournament

I am playing a live tournament with a "Progressive Clock", saying 15/20/30 min clock.

What does this mean?

Comment: Did you try asking the dealer, or looking for a sign with the room's rules?

Comment: This sounds like it is referring to the timer for increase in blinds, but I have not heard of something like this.

Comment: The name makes sense but I had not heard said like that.  I wonder how many times the blinds go up at each clock.  It would not make sense to just do one level at 15.  Not a duplicate but a related question https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/609/how-do-i-structure-the-blind-levels-of-a-tournament-to-run-for-a-certain-length

Answer (score 2):

A progressive clock means the blind levels gradually get longer. In this case the blind levels start with 15 min levels, then 20 and finally 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out it meant at the end of every break the clock would increase (so every 6 levels or so)

Answer (score 0):

Give the check to Raymond. I just ran some number out of curiosity.

Assume 12 levels, split the level timing equally, and double the blinds.

```
level    sb    bb   min  int
    1     1     2     0   15
    2     2     4    15 
    3     4     8    30 
    4     8    16    45 
    5    16    32    65   20
    6    32    64    85 
    7    64   128   105 
    8   128   256   125 
    9   256   512   155   30
   10   512  1024   185 
   11  1024  2048   215 
   12  2048  4096   245
```